# "Variable must be final" error preventing for loop from adding ActionListeners to objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to be able to add ActionListeners to java swing objects efficiently using a `for` loop. However, I always run into this error: `Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final` and it will not add the ActionListeners.

Goal: When a JButton in the `button` ArrayList is clicked, the corresponding JTextField in the `textfield` ArrayList to be cleared.

```
ArrayList <JButton> button = new ArrayList <JButton>();
ArrayList <JTextField> textfield = new ArrayList <JTextField>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  //Adds 10 JButtons / JTextfields to their corresponding ArrayLists
    button.add (new JButton());
    textfield.add (new JTextField());
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   //Adds ActionListeners to the JButtons in the buttons ArrayList
    button.get(i).addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            textfield.get(i).setText("");   //This is where the "variable must be final" stuff comes in, for loop won't run
        }
    });
}

public void makeFrame () {
    ...
    //Make JFrame and add all the JButtons and JTextFields from the ArrayLists
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for variable itself.Replace with Same listener for all buttons

```
   ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textfield.get(button.indexOf(e.getSource())).setText("");
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        button.get(i).addActionListener(listener);
    }
```

This will find the index of Button from the button list and pass that index to find the textfield from textfield list

Comment: Yes the action listener is same for all.The op needs corresponding textfield for a button.So i thought this will be simple and easy one

Comment: Wait so what would I add the ActionListener to?

Comment: @DavidWallace Yep ther is no need for that and I've updated it

Comment: @Nick refer the edited code.I guess that is enough for you